# About merge transformation

Tags: merge, ssis, transformation

[The output table and two source tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yrig.jpg)I am very new to SSIS. I was trying Merge tranformation with sorting. The data was sorted for Id (1,2,3) but from Id=4 onwards, there was no sorting. I have applied sort on both source tables.
Why such behaviour?
I have attached the image of the outcome and source tables.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like you've forgotten to link an image.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I have uploaded the image now.

Comment: If all of this data is from the same SQL Server, don't mess about with transformations in SSIS. Just use some SQL like this: `SELECT ID,Name from Table1 UNION ALL SELECT ID,Name from Table2`. BTW the image you attached is from SQL Server. If you ran a query on this without an order by, that data isn't ordered. Even if it is inserted in a certain order, this order is not preserved unless you add a column with the order, and order by that in your query

Comment: Thank you for checking, yes, all tables are from one SQL server. I was just practicing  merge tranforamtion in ssis but got confused in the sorting. I would keep in mind about what you said.